# Understanding the space $C([0,T]; L^{2}_{w})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence

In the study of PDEs I sometimes encounter spaces such as $C([0,T]; L^{2}_{w}(\mathbb{R})) $ or $C([0,T]; L^{\infty}_{w^{*}} (\mathbb{R}))$. Let's focus on the latter for now. The notation $L^{\infty}_{w^{*}}(\mathbb{R})$ is supposed to mean $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the weak-* topology.

However I don't really understand the difference between $X_{1} := C([0,T]; L^{\infty}_{w^{*}}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $X_{2} := C([0,T]; L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$. If I say $f \in X_{1}$ then how is this different to saying $f \in X_{2}$?

I know that the weak-* topology is of course different to the usual strong topology; it is the the coarsest topology for which the evaluation maps $\hat{x} \mapsto f(x)$ are continuous. The notion of convergence is also different: we say $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{\infty}_{w^{\star}}$ if

$$\forall g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}), \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n g ~\text{d}x = \int_{\Omega} f g ~\text{d}x.$$

However I don't know what the 'practical' difference is between saying $f \in X_{1}$ and $f \in X_{2}$. I would appreciate if someone can help me understand the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are spaces of continuous functions from the topological space $[0,T]$ to two different topological spaces $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

These spaces are different. In your example, $X_2 \subset X_1$.
The reverse inclusion is not true.
Here is an example: define
$$
f(t) = \chi_{(0,t)} \in L^\infty(\mathbb R).
$$
Then $f \in X_1$ but not in $X_2$: $\|f(t)-f(s)\|_{L^\infty}=1$ for $t\ne s$ hence $f\not \in X_2$. And
for fixed $g$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} (f(t)-f(s))g\ dx= \int_{(s,t)} g(x)dx
$$
has small absolute value for $s\approx t$ (by absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral). Hence $f\in X_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't see why $f \in X_{1}$ but not $X_{2}$ in your example.

Comment: Each individual output of the mapping $f(t)$ is an element of $L^\infty$, but the mapping $t\to f(t)$ is not continuous in the strong topology since $\lim_{s\to t} \|f(s)-f(t)\|_{L^\infty}=1$. Recall that such a map is continuous w.r.t. the strong topology iff $\lim_{s\to t} \|f(s)-f(t)\|_{L^\infty}=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: @whpowell96 ah yes I see. So when we check the map $t \mapsto f(t)$ is continuous in the weak-* topology, we need to check that the map $$ t \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \phi ~dx$$ is continuous for any $\phi \in L^{1}$? Is that correct? Im probably overlooking something simple but why is that the case again?

Comment: Weak convergence means that $F(f(s))\to F(f(t))$ for any bounded linear functional $F$. One can then characterize bounded linear functionals over $L^\infty$ as integrals against some class of finite measures and then proceed from there. $L^\infty$ happens to be more complicated than other $L^p$ spaces because its dual space can't be characterized neatly as some other function space. For the purposes of a counterexample, you can integrate against some function since $L^1 \subset (L^\infty)^*$, but $L^\infty$'s dual space is more complex so more is needed to show continuity.

Answer (score 1):

Daw's answer is correct but does not really explain why, so let me expand.

Say you have two topological spaces, $A$ and $B$, and that you decide to put a different topology on $B$ to turn it into $B'$ (so the underlying set is the same; simply, there's a different topology).

Then, there is no reason to *a priori* expect $C(A, B) = C(A, B')$, since $C(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the space of continuous maps from one space to the other. And the notion of "continuity" is heavily dependent on the topology of the target space (by definition).

---

So, unless the topologies of $B$ and $B'$ are equivalent (which is not the case in your example), you could very well cook up a sequence of paths that converges in $B$ but not in $B'$, or vice versa.

And so ultimately, you have $\boxed{C(A,B) \ne C(A, B')}$ (if the topologies are not equivalent).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me along with Daw's reply :)